# TypeScript Read import statements from seperate file

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript module/class which utilizes bunch of import statements. I want to move them into separate file and import that file. Tried doing that no luck. Is there anyway can i do this in typescript ?

Comment: Did you try a `/// <reference path="..."/>` comment pointing to the separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured the solution. All I need to do was include another file called **reference.ts** with following code

```
   /// <reference path="the modules or ts file you want import"/>
   ****export the modules here****
   export * from './filePath';
```

And import this reference file, where you need the imports statements for the modules listed in this file.