# Import many modules in a separate file to be used by another file

Tags: typescript, import, typescript2.0

I'm importing many modules from many files. Is there a way to have all the import files in a separate file? I'm using module type: es2015
example:

```
import {...} from '....1';
import {...} from '....2';
import {...} from '....';
import {...} from '....300';
```

I then import this file in the file that I need the imported modules like so:

```
import * as IMPORTS from '...'
```

Needless to say the references are not being found.

I also have tried the suggested way in [this stackoverlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702949/typescript-read-import-statements-from-seperate-file'%3E) with no luck.

---

Here's what I did so far:

1. In a separate file have all the import files.
2. In another file have ///`<reference path='path to file above' />` and export * from 'above'.
3. In the file I want to use all those imports, have import * as ...
   from 'file from step 2'.

I get a not found error on any of those modules that I try to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing all **imports** in the file created in step 1 with **exports**. This way there is no need for an extra intermediary file (step 2). Step three from the top is the same though I'm importing from the first file now.